# How would I use \etocsettocsetyle to remove the header of my local TOC?

Tags: table-of-contents, etoc

I am very new to Latex so I would appreciate if you'd explain it in simple steps. I don't want it to say "contents", I just want it to list the contents.

I tried setting the font size using code like

```
\etocsettocstyle{\size{\small}}
```

but without luck since I have no idea what keywords I can use.

Comment: `\etocsettocstyle{}{}`?

Answer (score 3):

Apparently just writing

```
\etocsettocstyle{}{}
\localtableofcontents
```

generates a local table of contents without the "contents" title.

Comment: Sorry, it is usually up to you to ask one of the commenters to provide an answer, not grabbing a comment 'solution' ....

Comment: I didn't even realize his answer was the solution until you said so. I thought he asked me to clarify. Sorry.

Comment: Upvoted. Welcome to TeX.SX.